# Example where automorphism group of Cayley graph of $G$ is not $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs

Clearly, $G$ is a subgroup of the automorphism group of a Cayley graph $\Gamma$ of $G$, because $G$ acts on $\Gamma$. I know plenty of examples where $G = \text{Aut}(\Gamma)$, but what is an example where the automorphism group of $\Gamma$ is larger than $G$?

Comment: Take $G=\mathbb{Z}_4$ with generator set $S=\{1,2,3\}$. The resulting Cayley graph is the complete graph $K_4$. The automorphism group is then $S_4\neq \mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: Another example. Take $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with generator set $S=\{(1,1)\}$. The resulting Cayley graph is a disjoint union of two copies of $K_2$. The resulting automorphism group has 8 elements.

Comment: Any Cayley graph for an abelian group with exponent greater than two - the inversion map fixes 1 and has order two.

Comment: And my final comment, take $G=\mathbb{Z}_n$ with $S=\{1\}$. This is a cyclic graph which has the dihedral group $D_n$ as its automorphism group.

Comment: "I know plenty of examples where $G = \operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$...". I am skeptical here - I can only name one (the trivial group!).

Comment: Examples where $G = \text{Aut}(\Gamma)$ seem pretty common. Some reflection groups come to mind, for instance the spherical $(2,3,5)$ group and the Euclidean $(2,3,6)$ reflection group. @user1729

Comment: A closely related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098115/when-is-the-automorphism-group-of-the-cayley-graph-of-g-just-g

Comment: @Lee The cyclic group of order two also works! My comment started life as "it seems like a more interesting question to find examples of groups where $G=\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$", but that seemed too dismissive at the time (now I feel it seems *less* dismissive!). I still think this is an interesting questions though, but have no time! I guess it isn't as simple as "$G=\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$ if and only if $\operatorname{Out}(G)=1$"?

Comment: @Lee So it turns out that they *are* very common, at least amongst finite groups. In particular, if $G$ is non-abelian with order coprime to $6$ then $G$ has some Cayley graph $\Gamma$ such that $Aut(\Gamma)=G$ (https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v24/cjm1972v24.0993-1008.pdf MR319804). If $G$ is abelian, and not one of $7$ specified groups, then then $G$ has some Cayley graph $\Gamma$ such that the natural empbedding of $G$ in $Aut(\Gamma)$ has index at most two (Imrich, W. & Watkins, M.E. Period Math Hung (1976) 7: 243. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02017943 ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $\Gamma$ is the undirected graph underlying the Cayley graph*, easy examples are found with cyclic groups:

- The Cayley graph of $\mathbb{Z}_n=\langle 1\rangle$ is a regular $n$-gon. The automorphism group of a regular $n$-gon is the dihedral group of order $2n$, $D_{n}$.
- The Cayley graph of $\mathbb{Z}=\langle 1\rangle$ is a straight line. The automorphism group of a straight line is the infinite dihedral group, $D_{\infty}$.

In each of these cases, $G$ has index two in $\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$. The extra symmetries come from "flipping" the graph.

---

*Without this assumption, $G\cong\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$. That is, a group $G$ is the automorphism group of any associated Cayley graph. Which is kinda the point of Cayley graphs...

Comment: About the asterisk comment, this is to say that the Cayley graph as a digraph is will possess $G$ as its automorphism group. Is that correct?

Comment: @Chickenmancer No - a Cayley graph is a *coloured/labelled* digraph. For example, consider the Klein $4$-group $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, and take the the generating set $S=\{ (0, 1), (1, 0)\}$. The corresponding digraph can be rotated, but this rotation is incompatible with the colouring. Indeed, rotation has order $4$ but $G$ contains no element of order $4$.